# Avoid some contact to receive email RaiseError - Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I need to avoid some contact to receive an email and collect their email addresses which is included in a DE.

What is the best way to go for this scenario?

Shall I use Ampscript and **RaiseError** to stop the send for these subscribers or would be better to use **Exclusion Script** (which is still not very clear to me)?

If more appropriated I would consider to use also SSJS with try/catch.

This email should be used in a Guided Send or in a Journey Builder.

Thank you

Comment: are you not able to suppress them during your send time? If it is a triggered send email, I would consider using the exclusion script rather than raiseError.

Comment: thanks @brad, do u mean with auto-suppression list? But then I cannot send other type of email to those contacts, right?

Comment: i was referring to exclusions area during the guided send, however, this doesn't incline if it is a triggered send or journey builder send.

Comment: Hi @eeadev, can you give some more details on what email activity you want these records excluded & details collected? Guided Send, Triggered, Automation Studio, Journey Builder, RMM, etc?

Comment: thanks Cameron, it should be a guided Send or a JB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommendation would be to use Exlcusion Script - with RaiseError, the send will be stopped but I believe it still adds to the send email count. If the condition to identify the contacts you need to exclude is something simple, you can try it in the Exclusion script itself (remember the expression must evaluate to be true).

Other option is to create a filtered DE using the conditions to exclude so that you have these contacts in the new filtered DE (let's call it SuppressionDE). Now you can use this DE in the Exclusion Script as mentioned in [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339899&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1).

Comment: thanks kris, can I also populate a DE inside an exclusion script, for instance using insertDE()?

Comment: I believe that you cannot do insert within an exclusion script - basically the principle of the exclusion script is that it should be a single statement that should evaluate to true or false - it may have nested functions within itself - but in the end, you cannot have multiple execution statements in the Exclusion script.